# how to use the CloudWatch UI to search for logs that in JSON format (having a field, date range, regex)?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I need to be able to search logs in json format. 
having fields, date ranges and regex

I have tried using cloudwatch logs insights. Not much help available on the syntax

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

## sample logs

```
--
response-hrtime: [
0,
4499325
]
--
req-headers:
{
    "x-forwarded-for": "118.209.107.66",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "host": "admin-api.different.com.au",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5d401189-0cc67ea4f09636dc75337048",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "origin": "https://owner.different.com.au",
    "authorization": "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTQ2NCwicm9sZUlkIjoyLCJ0aW1lem9uZSI6IkF1c3RyYWxpYS9TeWRuZXkiLCJuYW1lIjoiVGltb3RoeSBEYWhtIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtb3J0NTZ4QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImRldmljZUlkIjoiMTY3MTQzNDc2NV9XaW5kb3dzX0Nocm9tZSIsImRldmljZVR5cGUiOiJ3ZWIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjQ0Nzk4ODAsImV4cCI6MTU2NTY4OTQ4MH0.rfFSdhjB0W28hRZ4JcCQotE560eoB2KuvuQSHhDTVWc",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://owner.different.com.au/",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "if-none-match": "W/\"18f-GccQkGyTnnznHIXFCWdt4Q\""
}
```

How can I search for a particular field? How do I filter messages

Answer (score 0):

```
fields @Timestamp, @message | filter @message like /PARTICULAR_FIELD/
```

Please Try this